# Redux useDispatch return an Array React Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-hooks

I made Redux using useDispatch in React Hooks but when I call to dispatch the result becomes Array instead of a string.

[image: Redux]

My code for dispatch

```
//Variable for dispatch and useSelector
  const profileStore = useSelector(state => state)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

//Code dispatch
     <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => dispatch(profileAction('Profile Change'))}>
        <Text>helo</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
```

My reducers

```
import { PROFILE_SAMPLE } from '../types'


export default (state = 'Prev State Profile', { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {

  case PROFILE_SAMPLE:
    return { ...state, ...payload }

  default:
    return state
  }
}
```

My Actions

```
import {PROFILE_SAMPLE} from '../types'
export const profileAction = (payload) => ({
  type: PROFILE_SAMPLE,
  payload
})
```

Comment: Don't spread the payload in your switch case. Instead only return payload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are spreading your string value and returning an object on updating reducer.

If you want to simply replace the string update it like

```
case PROFILE_SAMPLE:
    return payload
```

or if you want to merge the string update it like

```
case PROFILE_SAMPLE:
    return `${state}${payload}`
```

Comment: I think in this case simply returning `payload` *as* the new state is sufficient.

Comment: @DrewReese Yes that is the ideal scenario but I just added another option just in case if that is what the OP was looking for